# How to add a rule to a RichText Editor using jquery.validate.js plugin?

Tags: 2013, jquery

I'm currently adding some customizations to a SharePoint 2013 form using jQuery.

I could add some rules to the 'input' and 'select' elements, but I can't do it for a RichText Editor. Did anyone try it?

```
$('div[id*="Pepe"][class*="ms-rtestate-write"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages:
    {
        required: 'Pepe is required'
    }
});
```

Turning on the the debug option on $('form').validate(...) I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself.

Solomonic solution: I didn't need a rich text type, so I changed the type to 'plain text'.

Now my validation is the following and it works like a charm:

```
$('textarea[title="Pepe"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages:
    {
        required: 'Pepe is required'
    }
});
```